# leading behavior of $y''=\sqrt{x} y$ at $0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

I would like to find the leading behavior at the irregular singular point at $x=0$.

First substitute $y = e^{S(x)}$, we obtain 
$$S'' + (S')^2 = \sqrt x \quad \quad (\star)$$
testing the two assumptions that $S'' << (S')^2$ and $(S')^2 << S''$ as $x\rightarrow 0$, we see that $S''$ is the dominating term which gives 
$$S'' \sim \sqrt x,$$
so $S\sim \frac{4}{15}x^{5/2}$ as $x\rightarrow 0$.

Now assume $S(x) = \frac{4}{15}x^{5/2} + C(x)$, from $S'' \sim \sqrt x$, I think we get $C'' << \sqrt x$ and $C' << x^{3/2}$. Plug this new $S$ into $(\star)$, we get 
$$C'' + \frac{4}{9} x^3 + 2\frac{2}{3}x^{3/2} C' + (C')^2 = 0$$
I know $(C')^2 <<  2\frac{2}{3}x^{3/2} C'$ so 
$$C'' + \frac{4}{9} x^3 + 2\frac{2}{3}x^{3/2} C'\sim 0 $$
but how could I simplify it further to something that can easily solve for $C$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $y(x)=x^rf(x^s)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^{r+sk}$, then
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(r+sk)(r+sk-1)x^{r+sk-2}=y''(x)=\sqrt{x}y(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^{r+sk+\frac12}.
$$
Identifying the second term on the left with the first term on the right and so on gives $r+(k+1)s-2=r+ks+\frac12\implies s=\frac52$. The indicial equation $r(r-1)=0$ has $r=0$ or $r=1$. The further coefficients follow the recursion
$$
a_{k}=\frac1{(r+\frac52k)(r+\frac52k-1)}a_{k-1}
$$
so that the first coefficients are (with $a_0=1$)
\begin{array}{cc|c}&r=0&r=1\\\hline
a_1=&\frac{4}{15}&\frac4{35}\\
a_2=&\frac1{75}&\frac2{525}\\
...
\end{array}
or inserted into the expansion of the solutions
$$
y_1(x)=1+\frac{4}{15}x^{\frac52}+\frac1{75}x^5+...\\
y_2(x)=x\left(1+\frac4{35}x^{\frac52}+\frac2{525}x^5+...\right)
$$

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Is there a way to find the leading behavior from this? Because the only definition for leading behavior is from finding $S(x)$ and etc.

Comment: You are free to translate the power series back into exponential form, $y_1(x)\approx \exp(\frac4{15}x^{5/2})$, $y_2(x)\approx x\exp(\frac4{35}x^{5/2})$. The next term you get from $e^{-az}(1+az+bz^2)\approx 1-\frac12a^2z^2+bz^2$ so that $y_1(x)\approx\exp(\frac4{15}x^{5/2}-\frac{1}{45}x^5)$ etc.

Comment: Okay, so it seems from my calculation, I would need to assume $x^{3/2}C' << C''$ which turns the equation to $C'' \sim - \frac{4}{9}x^3$ and we get $C \sim - \frac{1}{45}x^5$. And will your method work for irregular singular points in general? It is weird that it is not mentioned in the book by Bender and Orszag

Comment: Note that apart from the half-power, your equation is not very much singular. For $x\ge0$ the function $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x}y$ is continuous.

Comment: And the approach to consider $y(x)=x^rf(x^s)$ can be used in general to transform Airy-type equations $y''=x^ay$ into the form of Bessel equations or similar that have named basis solutions.